# Neural network agent, balancing a square

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, box2d, agent

For this class (data and image processing) i have to balance 4 poles within a cart with use of a neural network. The package i have to use is Box2d. i have to change the agent class so it will make 4 poles that make a square that balances in a cart

i have tried to change the radiants and angles of the poles but i cant get it to show up like a square (image)[how i need it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4b0k.png). But my code will only show this [enter how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jEDZ.png). The cart is supposed to balance the poles and create a new agent if the poles fall, it is training to balance the poles in a square form. Does somebody know how to fix this?

````
import random
import numpy as np
from Box2D import b2Vec2
from neuralNetwork import NeuralNetwork

class Agent():  
    # Static fields
    widthPlateau = 1.0
    heightOfPlateau = 0.05 
    factor = 400
    plateauIsInitialized = False
    def __init__(self, positionOfAgent, world):
        # Static fields, the plateau is a common field to share by all agents
        if not Agent.plateauIsInitialized:
            Agent.plateau = world.CreateStaticBody(position = (positionOfAgent[0], positionOfAgent[1] - 0.5 * Agent.heightOfPlateau))
            Agent.plateau.CreatePolygonFixture(box = (0.5 * Agent.widthPlateau, 0.5 * Agent.heightOfPlateau), density = 1, friction = 0.0)
            Agent.plateauIsInitialized = True
            
        # Local geometry/parameters of agent
        self.positionOfAgent  = positionOfAgent     
        self.l                = 1.0
        self.widthPole        = 0.06 * self.l
        self.widthCart        = 0.20 * self.l
        self.heightCart       = 0.50 * self.widthCart
        self.m                = 1.0
        self.M                = 1.0        
        self.maxForce         = 50.0
        self.angleTreshHold   = np.radians(12.5)
        self.neuralNet        = NeuralNetwork([4, 8, 1])
        self.inputs           = [0 for i in range(self.neuralNet.numberOfInputs)]        
        self.world            = world
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.isAlive          = True
        self.fitness          = 0
        self.timeNoDisturb    = 250.0        
        self.destroy()        
        self.createAgent()

    def createAgent(self):
        # The categoryBits flag can be thought of as the fixture saying 'I am a ...', 
        # and the maskBits is like saying 'I will collide with a ...'. 
        # The important point is that these conditions must be satisfied for both fixtures in order for collision to be allowed
        CATEGORY_BITS = 0x0001
        MASK_BITS = 0x0002
        
        cartPosition = [self.positionOfAgent[0] - 0.5 * self.widthCart,  
                    self.positionOfAgent[1] - 0.5 * self.heightCart]
        self.cart = self.world.CreateDynamicBody(position = cartPosition)
        self.cart.CreatePolygonFixture(box = (0.5 * self.widthCart, 0.5 * self.heightCart), 
                                       density = 1.0, friction = 0.0, categoryBits = CATEGORY_BITS, maskBits = MASK_BITS)
 
        self.poles = [None, None, None, None]
        multiplesOfHalfPoles = [[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [-1, 1, 0], [-1, 0, -1]]
        angles = np.radians([-45, -45 + 90, -45 + 90 + 90, -45 + 90 + 90 + 90])

        # Create the poles and adjust their positions and angles
        for i in range(4):
            if i == 0 or i == 3:
                # For the first and last poles, set the position within the cart
                polePosition = [cartPosition[0] + multiplesOfHalfPoles[i][0] * 0.25 * self.l * np.sin(-angles[0]) +
                                multiplesOfHalfPoles[i][1] * 0.25 * self.l * np.sin(-angles[1]) +
                                multiplesOfHalfPoles[i][2] * 0.25 * self.l * np.sin(-angles[2]),
                                cartPosition[1] + multiplesOfHalfPoles[i][0] * 0.25 * self.l * np.cos(-angles[0]) +
                                multiplesOfHalfPoles[i][1] * 0.25 * self.l * np.cos(-angles[1]) +
                                multiplesOfHalfPoles[i][2] * 0.25 * self.l * np.cos(-angles[2])]
            else:
                # For the middle poles, set the position on top of the first and last poles
                polePosition = [self.poles[i-1].position.x,
                                self.poles[i-1].position.y + 0.5*self.l]
   
            self.poles[i] = self.world.CreateDynamicBody(position = polePosition, angle = angles[i])
            self.poles[i].CreatePolygonFixture(box = (0.5 * self.widthPole, 0.5 * self.l), 
                                       density = 1.0, friction = 0.0, categoryBits = CATEGORY_BITS, maskBits = MASK_BITS)     
        
        print(polePosition)
        # Set masses of fixtures
        self.cart.mass = self.M
        for pole in self.poles:
            pole.mass = self.m
     
        # Joints
        self.world.CreatePrismaticJoint(bodyA=Agent.plateau, bodyB=self.cart,
                                        localAnchorA=(0.0, 0.5 * Agent.heightOfPlateau), localAnchorB=(0.0, -0.5 * self.heightCart))        
        self.world.CreateRevoluteJoint(bodyA=self.cart, bodyB=self.poles[0], 
                                    localAnchorA=(0.0, 0.0), localAnchorB=(0.0, -0.5 * self.l))
        self.world.CreateWeldJoint(bodyA=self.poles[0], bodyB=self.poles[1], 
                                localAnchorA=(0.0, 0.5 * self.l), localAnchorB=(0.0, -0.5 * self.l))
        self.world.CreateWeldJoint(bodyA=self.poles[1], bodyB=self.poles[2], 
                                localAnchorA=(0.0, 0.5 * self.l), localAnchorB=(0.0, -0.5 * self.l))
        self.world.CreateWeldJoint(bodyA=self.poles[2], bodyB=self.poles[3], 
                                localAnchorA=(0.0, 0.5 * self.l), localAnchorB=(0.0, -0.5 * self.l))
        self.world.CreateRevoluteJoint(bodyA = self.poles[3], bodyB = self.cart, 
                                       localAnchorA = (0.0, 0.5 * self.l), localAnchorB = (0.0, 0.0))
        
    def destroy(self):
        # Check if the three bodies exist, if cart exists, the other also have been instantiated
        if not hasattr(self, 'cart'): 
            return
        self.world.DestroyBody(self.cart)
        for pole in self.poles:
            self.world.DestroyBody(pole)

    def disturb(self):
        self.timeNoDisturb -= 1
        self.timeNoDisturb = np.clip(self.timeNoDisturb, 0.0, 250.0)
        if abs(self.cart.linearVelocity[0]) < 0.01 and abs(self.poles[1].angularVelocity) < 0.01 and self.timeNoDisturb == 0:
            signForce = int(2 * ((self.cart.position[0] - self.positionOfAgent[0]) < 0) - 1)
            force = signForce * random.uniform(0.35 * self.maxForce, 0.55 * self.maxForce)
            self.timeNoDisturb = 250
            f = b2Vec2(force, 0.0)
            self.poles[1].ApplyForce(f, self.poles[1].worldCenter, wake = True)

    def update(self):
        if not self.isAlive:
            return  False          

        # Pass input data
        theta = self.poles[1].angle - np.radians(90)
        thetaDot = self.poles[1].angularVelocity 
        xDot = self.cart.linearVelocity[0]
        x = self.cart.position[0] - self.positionOfAgent[0]       
        self.inputs[0] = thetaDot
        self.inputs[1] = theta / self.angleTreshHold
        self.inputs[2] = xDot
        self.inputs[3] = x / (0.5 * Agent.widthPlateau)
                    
        if abs(theta) > self.angleTreshHold or abs(x) > 0.5 * Agent.widthPlateau:
            self.isAlive = False
            return True
            
        # Compute output of network
        outputs = self.neuralNet.update(self.inputs)
        F = 2.0 * (outputs[0] - 0.5) * self.maxForce
        f = b2Vec2(F, 0.0)
        self.cart.ApplyForce(f, self.cart.worldCenter, wake = True)        
  
        # Alive!, so update fitness
        self.fitness += 1   
        
        # Add, if appropriate, some disturbance
        self.disturb()
    
    def draw(self, interface, screen):
        if not self.isAlive:
            return        

        for pole in self.poles:
            for fixture in pole.fixtures:
                shape = fixture.shape
                localVerticesAgent =  [pole.transform * v for v in shape.vertices]
                scaledVerticesAgent = [v * Agent.factor for v in localVerticesAgent]
                globalVerticesAgent = [(v[0] + 0.5 * screen.get_width(), 0.5 * screen.get_height() - v[1]) for v in scaledVerticesAgent]
                interface.draw.polygon(screen, (255, 255, 0), globalVerticesAgent)
                interface.draw.polygon(screen, (0, 0, 0), globalVerticesAgent, 2)
            
        for fixture in self.cart.fixtures:
            shape = fixture.shape
            localVerticesAgent =  [self.cart.transform * v for v in shape.vertices]
            scaledVerticesAgent = [v * Agent.factor for v in localVerticesAgent]
            globalVerticesAgent = [(v[0] + 0.5 * screen.get_width(), 0.5 * screen.get_height() - v[1]) for v in scaledVerticesAgent]
            interface.draw.polygon(screen, (0, 0, 255), globalVerticesAgent, 5)            

    # Draw plateau
    @staticmethod
    def drawPlateau(interface, screen):
        for fixture in Agent.plateau.fixtures:
            shape = fixture.shape
            localVerticesPlateauBox = [Agent.plateau.transform * v for v in shape.vertices]
            scaledVerticesPlateauBox = [v * Agent.factor for v in localVerticesPlateauBox]
            globalVerticesPlateauBox = [(v[0] + 0.5 * screen.get_width(), 0.5 * screen.get_height() - v[1]) for v in scaledVerticesPlateauBox]
            interface.draw.polygon(screen, (0, 255, 0), globalVerticesPlateauBox)```
````